# vcpkg : How to install ceres-solver in windows

Tags: mingw-w64, vcpkg, ceres-solver

I tried to install ceres-solver from vcpkg. Relevant libraries(ex:glog) has been installed, but I cannot install ceres with this log.

Fatal error:
internal/ceres/CMakeFiles/ceres_internal.dir/covariance_impl.cc.obj: file too big

I think I could add a build option "-Wa,-mbig-obj", but I don't know where to write it. Am I wrong? Please help me.

OS : Windows11,
compiller : MinGW

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Builds fine on my Windows 11 with MinGW-w64 using CMake and Ninja with the following CMake flags: `-DCUSTOM_BLAS:BOOL=ON -DEIGENSPARSE:BOOL=ON -DLAPACK:BOOL=ON -DCXSPARSE:BOOL=OFF -DOPENMP:BOOL=ON -DSCHUR_SPECIALIZATIONS:BOOL=ON -DSUITESPARSE:BOOL=ON -DGFLAGS:BOOL=OFF -DMINIGLOG:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_BENCHMARKS:BOOL=OFF`. It works with both `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF` and `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON`.